# hash value of int is the same number

Tags: c++, hash, stl

Why does hash return *itself* as a hash value?

I've set a hash and a hash side-by-side, 
and the one for string works as expected, while the int one produces itself as a hash value!

Is this how it should work ?

```
hash<int> h;
for( int i=0 ; i<15 ; ++i )
{
    cout << "int hash for " << i << " is " << h(i) << endl; 
}

hash<string> hs;
for( int i=0; i<15; ++i) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << i;
    cout << "string hash for " << i << " is " << hs(ss.str()) << endl; 
}
```

and the result is

```
+ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wextra main.cpp
+ ./a.out
int hash for 0 is 0
int hash for 1 is 1
int hash for 2 is 2
int hash for 3 is 3
int hash for 4 is 4
int hash for 5 is 5
int hash for 6 is 6
int hash for 7 is 7
int hash for 8 is 8
int hash for 9 is 9
int hash for 10 is 10
int hash for 11 is 11
int hash for 12 is 12
int hash for 13 is 13
int hash for 14 is 14
string hash for 0 is 2297668033614959926
string hash for 1 is 10159970873491820195
string hash for 2 is 4551451650890805270
string hash for 3 is 8248777770799913213
string hash for 4 is 16215888864653804456
string hash for 5 is 7995238595416485409
string hash for 6 is 3835993668518112351
string hash for 7 is 905566266843721762
string hash for 8 is 17899137375351314596
string hash for 9 is 6623666755989985924
string hash for 10 is 2594088158685378223
string hash for 11 is 9717255990760309898
string hash for 12 is 11194622142508650503
string hash for 13 is 15638310844945205280
string hash for 14 is 1116181219906060362
```

you can see it running on:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0e1536d19c533f

Comment: Why *shouldn't* it produce itself?

Comment: @NPE: so if have an unordered_set<int> and I insert to it numbers that are multiples of its bucket_count() I'm bound to get them all in the same bucket ?

Comment: Well, no matter what you do there is always going to exist a pathological case...

Comment: Understand that a hash, as used to construct a hashtable, is different from a cryptographic hash.  For a hashtable you merely want different input values to have a high probability of producing different output values (and this is what you're getting).  For a cryptographic hash you want very minor changes to the input to produce large and unpredictable changes to the output.

Comment: Some hash algorithms do attempt to avoid the pathological case where a "rhythmic" input, varying in fixed increments, can produce collisions.  But simply avoiding bucket counts that are 2**n or some multiple of 10 (hence a prime is often a good choice) will generally bypass most such hazards.

Comment: @HotLicks: I see, so that's why the bucket_count() doesn't exactly double very time the hash table expands... So what you're saying is that I shouldn't  look for another hash generator, because it's practically impossible to bump into such a periodicity of ints that will cause overpopulation to some buckets of the unordered_map

Comment: It's not impossible to run into a degenerate case, but it's rare.  Whether it's worth worrying about depends on several factors -- anticipated key patterns, your collision strategy, total number of entries expected, how performance critical the whole thing is, etc.  There is the problem that this can be a whack-a-mole thing -- "fixing" this problem can increase the probability of collision for the more normal case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't confuse an object's hash value with it's slot index in the hash you may be storing it in. The hash value is simply a best-attempt at a near-to-unique numerical value for a given input value.

What your code demonstrated it was that, for each integer value you hashed, a unique hash value was returned.

That's an ideal hash function.

```
std::hash<int, std::string> hashTable;

hashTable[42] = "hello";
```

The hash value of 42 is 42. But there probably aren't 42 buckets in this hash. `operator[]` is overloaded here and is going to constrain the `hash value` by the hash distribution (number of buckets) to determine which slot to put you in.

```
key = 42
hashValue = 42
hashKey = 42 % m_bucket.size() // which bucket to look for this key in
```

Comment: is this a suitable hash function to use in an unordered_set/map then ? It seems like I can easily fill up a single bucket of the hash table, which defeats the purpose of having an unordered map after all...

Comment: Again, the *hash value* is only part of determining the position of an entry. When you access the hash as `hashTable[hashValue]` operator[] is overloaded and will perform some operation on `hashValue` to determine which slot to use, e.g. `hashKey = hashValue % m_buckets.size();`

Comment: When mapping from one space to a larger or equal-size space, we simply cannot improve the distribution. Since the same value always maps to the same hash, the distribution of the output hashes is always the same as the distribution of the input values, as long as the hashes are perfectly collision-free. But if we do constraint the size of the *final* hash space (e.g., use modulo to fit the size of a container), then the plain identity mapping may not be good enough, and we may need better ways to uniformly distribute the hashes.

Answer (score 13):

> Why does hash return itself as a hash value?

Quite bluntly, because it can. This is the most efficient thing to do, and it gives you a perfect hash function for integers. You simply cannot do better than that!

Comment: It has a drawback of not having uniform hash distribution for most usage cases. It is not required by a standard, yet many applications rely on this property.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is how it should work. The hash function returns an integer, and the input is an integer, so just returning the input value results in the most unique hash possible for the hash type.

Answer (score 2):

A hash function is an injective mapping from a value to a fixed size value. If the source and the target domain are identical it seems the identity is a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 1):

A hash function has to produce a the same, `size_t`-type value for identical inputs, and try hard to return different values for different inputs. For integers at most as wide as `size_t`, the integer itself satisfies these requirements and is cheap to compute.